# How to access controller function in view using zendframework

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Hi am new to zendframewrok,

In my controller, I have public function with arguments like this

```
    public function ArrayRetrive($array, $todelete)
{
    $res='';
    if(@array_key_exists($todelete, $array)) {
        $res=$array[$todelete];
    }
    else{
    foreach( $array as $key=>$value )
    {
        if (is_array($array[$key]) && array_key_exists($todelete, $array[$key])) {
        $res=$array[$key][$todelete];
        }
    }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Now i want to access this function in view index.phtml,

I don't know how to do that?am stuck here.

Please help me any one

Comment: In your controller add $this->view->res=$res; and call the value in index.phtml as <?php echo $this->res;?>

Comment: How it is work? I called that res variable inside of function.
what am exactly asking I want to access this function from view like
$this->ArrayRtrive($array, 'status')

Comment: @use3535066 - you have to assign the value in controller and then only you can access the value in view.

Comment: am trying this one but it's not working? Because, actually I need to pass the function argument from view page
for example I have big multidimensional associative array, I want to took only one value from the array, so am passing the array & key into this function it will return the output.

Comment: write a custom view helper and assign the ($array, 'status') to your view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a view helper. Here it is a good/fast tutorial:
https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/zend-framework-2-create-your-custom-view-helper/